# How to get area and median from this graph

Tags: graphing-functions

I'm new to this site I hope someone can help me.
I have this graph.

[image]

That graph is real graph except for red line I drew to let you know which area I'm looking for. and the green line is median.

My question is how can I get area and median value(green line)? what formula or method should I use?

Thank you.

Comment: Mean lines are scary.

Comment: @B.Pasternak I'm sorry it is median not mean.